# Angular 2 global variable

Tags: angular

I am trying to set up a global service which can be accessed through out all the components, precisely I wish to store user related information using this service like roles, name etc. and use it later  in all components

I have tried with singleton, but It got clear after browser refresh.

How to achieve this any guidance will be appreciated.

The singleton service is like this:

```
    export class Principal{
    private isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
    private roles: Array<String>;
    private fullName: String;
    constructor(){} ;
    // getter and setter

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to have your service singleton save its state in a browser persistence storage if it is to survive a browser refresh. Add some of your singleton code to your original question and I will update this answer with code that saves its state in `sessionStorage`;

**UPDATE**

We can use the [angular2-localStorage](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage) module to accomplish this.

```
export class Principal{
    @SessionStorage() private isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
    @SessionStorage() private roles: Array<String>;
    @SessionStorage() private fullName: String;
    constructor(){} ;
    // getter and setter
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE**

Do not store any sensitive values here. Your backend API should NOT trust any of these values as the end user can easily change these.

With idomatic typescript you should prefer `get` and `set` accessors rather than getter and setter methods.

Comment: How can an end user change these values?

Comment: @vigamage -- in the example given a user could open the debugging console while the app is running and enter `sessionStorage.setItem('roles', 'admin');` to change the values. This is why nothing in the browser should ever be trusted. Just because the Angular app now thinks the user is an `admin` -- the backed API should throw an error when an `admin` API is called.

Comment: oh. Thank you for the information. So,, what is the way you suggest to store such data ?

Comment: Store anything like user roles behind an api on the server where it is safe.

Answer (score 1):

This corresponding service provider must be specified when bootstrapping your application or within the `providers` attribute of the main component.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ GlobalService ]);
```

or

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ GlobalService ]
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

This way all your components will share the same instance of the service.

Comment: Is there any way to get around having to write `import x from y` at the top of every file also? I'd like to have lodash as a global variable.